# Sales Report by Country

Tags: sales, reports, magento1.9.3, countries

I have customers from **Germany, Austria, & Switzerland** all using the same Store & StoreView.

Is there any way to get a sales report filtered by country?

Maybe with a short script or something?

I haven't found a way using Magento Default Reports.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for this **advanced report extension**

https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/magento-advanced-reports.html

Its shows reports by country.